# Execute Instructions on certain clients ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a Multi structured Ansible playbook yml with 6 Instructions and 2 client machines connected to the ansible server. I want to execute 3 Instructions on client1 and 3 on client2. both the clients, with their alias are at the EOF(ansible host file) I don't use any groups. How can I execute particular Instruction on specific machines.

Below is my clients in ansible hostfile:

```
client1 ansible_host=192.168.0.150 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=password

client2 ansible_host=192.168.0.110 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hosts:` variable in your play to specify where to run the tasks:

```yaml
---
- name: demo 1
  hosts: client1
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:

- name: demo 2
  hosts: client2
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:
```